# Undefined references to EGL functions?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl-es, kubeflow, egl

I am trying to compile the program below and run the executable on Ubuntu without UI. I am working in a Kubeflow notebook. This is a preliminary test to check that everything works fine in order to run [this repo](https://github.com/Sin3DM/Sin3DM/tree/main).

When I run the script, I get the error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cciku4KL.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `eglGetDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `eglInitialize'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `eglChooseConfig'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `eglCreateContext'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `eglCreatePbufferSurface'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `eglMakeCurrent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix the issue?

```cpp
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    EGLDisplay display;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLContext context;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLint num_config;

    // Get Display
    display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get EGL display." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize EGL
    if (!eglInitialize(display, 0, 0)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize EGL." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get Config
    if (!eglChooseConfig(display, NULL, &config, 1, &num_config)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to choose config." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create Context
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
    if (context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create EGL context." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a Pbuffer surface.
    const EGLint pbufferAttributes[] = {
        EGL_WIDTH, 10,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 10,
        EGL_NONE,
    };
    surface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, pbufferAttributes);
    if (surface == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create EGL surface." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the context current
    if (!eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to make context current." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "EGL initialization successful." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does [`eglGetError()`](https://registry.khronos.org/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglGetError.xhtml) return after the failed call?

Comment: I updated the text above with the error messages I get.

Comment: "When I run the script ..." - C++ is *not* a scripting language. Get you terminology right - you did not "run a script", you compiled a program and then ran the generated executable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Good point. Sorry for that. I was deep in Pythonland. I edited the post.